# xcode swift 3.0 parse JSON response

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to get the status code and put it in an if statement. This code will run in the xCode playground.

Right now **status** returns as **["200"]** with square brackets around it. If I remove the brackets it returns as **nil**.

How to I return status as 200 and put it in an if statement?

```
import Foundation

let str = "{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"],\"status\"[\"200\"],\"message\":\"User has been  created\",\"id\":null,\"username\":\"asdf\"}"//"{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]}"
let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do {
     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
     let status = json["status"] as? [String]

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Can you pleas show us what you have try.

Comment: Use SwiftyJSON for parsing

Comment: Use Alamofire for Json Parsing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this workaround:

```
let responseString = Optional("{\"status\":\"200\",\"message\":\"User has been created\",\"id\":null,\"username\":\"asdf\"}")
let responseData = responseString?.data(using: .utf8)
let dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData!, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>

let status = dict["status"] // optional value stored with "status" key in Dictionary
```

It seems that actually, Swift 3 refuses to compile using:

```
let dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseString?.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
```

Swift 3 claims that responseString?.data(using: .utf8)! should be unwrapped although it is already.

Answer (score -1):

```
let str = "{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"],\"status\":[\"200\"],\"message\":\"User has been  created\",\"id\":null,\"username\":\"asdf\"}"//"{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]}"
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    let status = json["status"] as? [String]
    let yourValue =  status?[0]

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I just add ( : ) after status in json formate to be invalid